# C# application is closed unexpectedly!

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm having a very frustrating problem. I have a c# win application. When I have clicked the button, the program closes itself after executed the click event handler. Even if I have debugged the code unfortunately I can't see any error, It just quits the program.

Where am I going wrong?

Here is the Code:

```
private void btnOpenFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DialogResult dg = fd1.ShowDialog();
            if (dg == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                lblInput.Text = fd1.SelectedPath;
                btnOpenFolder.Enabled = false;
                timerCallback = new TimerCallback(tmrQualityEvent);
                tmrQuality = new System.Threading.Timer(timerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
                Thread qualityThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(QualityMapOpenFolder));
                qualityThread.Start();
                QualityMapOpenFolder();
            }
    }

void QualityMapOpenFolder()
    {
        fileList.Clear();
        string path = lblInput.Text;
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(file) != ".kml")
                {
                    fileList.Add(file);
                }
            }
            SetProgressBarValue(0);
            ChangeFileNameLabel(fileList[0]);
            FileName = fileList[0];
        }
        else
            SetText("Please make sure you have correctly set the open folder path!", true);

        dataListQuality = GetInputData();

        SetText("Calculated Data has been created, please click process files...", false);
        SetProcessButtonStatus(true);
    }
```

Comment: Well you haven't shown us any code whatsoever, which makes it hard to diagnose the problem. I suggest you copy your code to somewhere safe, and then remove as much of it as you can while preserving the bad behaviour. Then you'll either know what's wrong, or be able to post that short but complete program for us to examine.

Comment: Please **take note** of my edits and stop shouting at us. While your problem is urgent _right now_, in three years when other people befit from this, you will have solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Attach an event handler to the [UnhandledException handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and log it. Should help you to find out why your application is crashing.

**Update**: Now that you have posted some code:

1. You seem to update UI elements from another thread which you start. You should access UI components only from the thread on which they were created (usually the main thread). Consider using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)
2. You start the `QualityMapOpenFolder` method on a thread and then you also call it after you started the thread - this seems a bit weird and has probably some unexpected side effects.

Comment: No , I was testing both calling it with thread and with out thread! I just forgot to delete second one!

Answer (score 0):

The common reason for this kind of behavior is unhandled exception in background thread. To prevent program.

@ChrisWue wrote on how to detect this kind of exceptions.

Also, often Windows Application log provides an insight on unhandled errors.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx) how to prevent killing app in this case.

Comment: Yes, I was using threads but it doesn't let me know where it crushes, but UnhandledException handler works great!! I can see now where it crushes. Thanks